# Symfony 3 - Handle login process manually

Tags: php, symfony

I try to handle the whole login process manually with a service defined like below

```
<?php

namespace StandardBundle\Security;

use \PDO;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;

class AuthenticateUser
{
    private $sesion;
    private $security;
    private $em;
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, TokenStorageInterface $security, EntityManagerInterface $em, EncoderFactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->security   = $security;
        $this->em      = $em;
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function identification($login, $passw)
    {
        if( ('' === $login || null === $login) || ('' === $passw || null === $passw) ) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Login and password can\'t be empty');
        }

        // getRepo
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository("StandardBundle:User");

        // getUser
        $user = $repo->findOneBy(array('username' => $login));

        // check user exists
        if(!$user){
            return false;
        }

        // get encoder
        $encoder = $this->factory->getEncoder($user);

        // get salt
        $salt = $user->getSalt();

        // Check password is valid
        if(!$encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $passw, $salt)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('Bad credentials');
        }

        // generate token
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', array('ROLE_VISITEUR'));
        // set token
        $this->security->setToken($token);

        // If the firewall name is not main, then the set value would be instead:
        // $this->get('session')->set('_token_XXXFIREWALLNAMEXXX', serialize($token));
        $this->session->set('_token_main', serialize($token));
        // save
        $this->session->save();
    }
}
```

And here is the loginAction in controller

```
<?php

public function loginAction(Request $request)
  {
    if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
      return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')){
        $authenticateUser = $this->get("standard.authenticate_user");
        $authenticateUser->identification('fakeuser','myfakepassw');
    }

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    $defaultData = array(
      //'action' => $this->generateUrl('login_check')
      'action' => $this->generateUrl('login_' . $request->getLocale())
    );

    $form = $this->createForm(LoginForm::class, array(), $defaultData);
    $form->get('_username')->setData($lastUsername);
    $form->get('_failure_path')->setData($request->getPathInfo());

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if (!is_null($error)) {
      $form->addError(
        new FormError($error->getMessage())
      );      
    }

    return $this->render('@Standard/login.html.twig', array(
      'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
  }
```

And my login.twig.html

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {% form_theme form _self %}

    {% block form_errors %}
      {% if errors is defined and errors|length > 0 %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          {% for error in errors %}
            <div>{{ error.message|trans }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}      
    {% endblock %}

    {{ form_errors(form) }}    

    <div class="form-group">
      {# Génération du label. #}
      {{ form_label(form.login, "LibLogin") }}
      {{ form_widget(form.login, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {# Génération du label. #}
      {{ form_label(form.passw, "LibPassw") }}
      {{ form_widget(form.passw, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}      
    </div>
      {{ form_widget(form.submit, {'label':'LibConnexion','attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}}) }}

    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

It seems to working well but when incorrect informations are provided my service throw a `BadCredentialsException` which is not catch by symfony and can't be get back with

```
$authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

// get the login error if there is one
$error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
```

Expected
[image]
Got
[image]

How tell to symfony to display my exception in the form error ?

Comment: why can't you catch it manually in loginAction and add it as an form->addError as everything already is not done as it's written in tha cookbook? :)

Comment: can you provide a link to the cook book ? I didn't find something like that..

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Comment: I do not use Guard...

Answer (score 0):

Have you displayed the form errors on your template?
`{{ form_errors(form) }}`
Like [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)...

Or you can perform your credentials check to the form using FormEvents, like [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html). Then proccess the form like [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms), meaning that the form is valid if the credentials are valid (then log the user in and redirect) or display form errors otherwise.

Comment: I did, I've updated question. I'm not sure to understand what's the difference between my way of process form into controller itself or by using a dedicated service like I do.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't you get the error after `$form->handleRequest($request);`? That is where you submit the form and get the data, etc.